# Profile shared library Android NDK application

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, profiling

I am developing an Android app which heavily uses NDK and also uses external shared libraries compiled from C++.

Those libraries contain various algorithms and I'd like to use profiling tools to boost performance of the code inside this library. Worth mentioning that I am building my C++ libraries with CMake.

Are there any tools for profiling that can be suitable for my case?

**Edit:**

Particularly, can I use [android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler) with my shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two methods that can be used with native Android C++ libraries.

1) "Intrusive" profiling. Compile your code with `-pg` and use android-ndk-profiler project to link everything up.

2) "Non-intrusive" way. Use [fplutil](https://google.github.io/fplutil/android_ndk_perf.html) `android_ndk_perf` to run `perf` on device. Follow their documentation for guidance.

1st way should work just about everywhere, while 2nd requires some support from Linux kernel and may not work properly on some devices.