# Android NDK profiling tools

Tags: android, android-ndk, profiling

Trying to profile my native libraries on Android, I have concerned that there is a lack of free profiling tools for this platform (specifically to profile native libraries).

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357601/profile-shared-library-android-ndk-application) and [here](https://www.virag.si/2015/08/profiling-native-ndk-code-in-android/) two alternatives are available:

1. [android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler): Intrusive profiling.
2. [fplutil](https://github.com/google/fplutil): Non-intrusive profiling.

The first option interferes in the execution while the profiler is active, and as the [readme file of the android-ndk-profiler](https://github.com/richq/android-ndk-profiler/blob/master/README.mkd) sais: "*As an alternative please try out Google's own FPL Utils - NDK perf, which provides a non-intrusive way to profile your applications using Linux perf*".

However, this new tool looks to only works on [two specific devices](https://github.com/google/fplutil/blob/master/bin/android_ndk_perf.py#L58):

```
## Set of tested devices that are known to support perf.
SUPPORTED_DEVICES = set([
    'mantaray',  # Nexus 10
    'nakasi',  # Nexus 7 (2012)
])
```

It looks like the device should have "Linux Perf" support to use fplutis profiler.

Is there any other device apart of Nexus 10 and Nexus 7 (2012) where this profiling tool can be used?

Is there a way to active this "Linux Perf" support on other devices? (changing the rom for example)

Any other (newer) alternative?

Thanks.

NOTE: Some other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446093/memory-debugging-tools-for-android-ndk-c-code) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703135/profiling-android-ndk-plain-c-c-executable) suggest to use Valgrid, but I assume that it is an old alternative, and it is deprecated nowadays.